# "Sought" vs. "searched"

Tags: word-choice, differences, simple-past

Can *sought* and *searched* be used interchangeably?

As in "we searched for an article" versus "we sought an article".

(Or if I got those two examples wrong, but there are correct examples where sought and searched have the same meaning, please correct me.)

Comment: _Sought_ is the old irregular weak past tense form of _seek_ (just like _wrought_ is the old irregular weak past tense form of _work_). It's archaic, and used only to impart an air of romance or something to a sentence, by those who appreciate such things. In Modern English, however, _seek_ (like _work_) is a **regular** weak verb, with a regular fused past tense/past participle form ending with the [`{-ED}` inflectional suffix](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf).

Comment: Had you made that an answer, rather than a comment, John, I would have been able to vote it up.

Comment: "Seeked"?  Let's try that out.  "We seeked for him, but didn't find him."  "I seeked to learn the secrets of the universe."  "They seeked a Sikh."  Sorry, that doesn't work at all, at least in my ears.  Sounds very odd and awkward.  I would use "sought" in all of those and would still feel very up-to-date, not archaic at all.  Prof @JohnLawler, I don't agree with you at all on this.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: Quite right, sorry. _Sought_ is indeed **still** the irregular weak past tense form of _seek_. _Sought_ still feels archaic, but that's probably because regular forms of _search_ (a different verb, borrowed ultimately from Latin) are used instead of _seek_ (a native Germanic verb with a different etymology). That's where I got confused. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think wrought is, however, seen as archaic

Comment: @RoryAlsop except in the case of iron.

Comment: @John: *Sought is archaic???* It's still the most common of the three phrases *sought, searched, looked for*. Maybe you don't use it, but lots of other people (including me) do. See [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sought%2Csearched%2Clooked+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csought%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csearched%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clooked%20for%3B%2Cc0). Maybe you're thinking that the meaning *"searched for"* is archaic, so *"I sought the treasure"* is archaic, but *"he sought to have the will invalidated"* isn't.

Comment: @PeterShor: I already called him on the carpet for that; you don't need to pile on, too! LOL.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: I'm calling him on the carpet for his later statement "Sought still feels archaic, but that's because regular forms of *search* are used instead of *seek*." I don't think that statement's true, either. I probably should have been clearer.

Comment: Fair enough, @PeterShor, but he did come right back and admit his error, including what you brought up, I think.  Whatever.  Let's roast him thoroughly, then!  :-)  It's more fun that way.

Comment: I would never use it as a regular verb; it has an archaic feel to me, rather like _seek_ itself. I'd use _look for_ or _search for_ instead of _seek_ or _sought_, which falute at altitudes where the air is usually too thin for me. They do occur in other words, idioms, and fixed phrases like _Seek and you shall find, (much-)sought-after, seeker, KILLER SOUGHT IN SHOOTING_.

Comment: @John Lawler Well, you live and learn. I'd no idea that 'wrought' was the past tense of work. My understanding had always been that it was the past of 'wreak'. In fact I am sure that I and lots of others have used it in that way; 'The midget submarines wrought havoc with the enemy's shipping...'

Comment: That is quite interesting, actually, and shows the versatility of vocabulary.  Two English speakers (@JohnLawler and I) who live about a 100 miles apart can have such a disparate understanding about such a basic word!  I queried a coworker about "sought" and he regarded it as the "correct" past-tense of seek, and not archaic at all.  He's a computer programmer, like me, so perhaps that explains it.  But I doubt it.  Like I say, interesting!

Comment: @WS2: I was ignorant of work/wrought myself.  I was aware of the word "wright" being a "worker" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright), but it never quite hit me about the result of a wright's (ahem) work being what he had "wrought".  And there we with "wrought iron" meaning "worked iron"!  Wow, that is so cool!  I love this language... it's quite nutty at times but contains so much that is utterly fascinating.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Interesting to hear that you live only 100 miles from John Lawler. Your state abbreviation of WA I had taken to mean  'Western Australia'. I bet that gets confusing.

Comment: @WS2 LOL!  Wow, I better change that.  Wouldn't want anyone to think I have an Aussie accent!  Even though I think the Aussie accent is one of the coolest on earth. Although there is no Olympia in Western Australia.

Comment: Does "search" and "look for" suggest that you have to look through an assortment of items, things, objects before finding it? "I searched/looked/sought high and low", and "Among the pile of papers she looked for/searched for/sought a faded note." *Sought* sounds odd used here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, "search" and "look for" do not necessarily suggest that you have to look through an assortment of items.  But you might.  As to "high and low" this is almost always used with "searched" or "looked"; I haven't seen "sought" used in that expression, but there's no reason you couldn't do so.  It fits, though some might find it a little odd.  As to the second example it doesn't sound odd to me.  It actually lends a bit of a formal tone to both expressions to use "sought".  To me, at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very squishy, actually.  In some cases you could interchange them and no problem with it.  But in others you couldn't.  In your example, they are equivalent.

"Seek"/"Sought" can be quite passive or much less active than "Search/Searched".  "Seek" can be quite theoretical, which "search" is not.

- "I seek for the greater good of all mankind."  I can sit in my easy chair and do this with my eyes closed, snoring softly.
- "I search for the greater good of all mankind."  This implies I am out of my chair and actively looking for it, as if it were some discreet object.

This isn't ironclad in all cases, however.  You could use "seek" like you would use "search", but possibly not the other way around.  In the children's game of "Hide and Seek", the seeker is definitely actively looking.  Unless being "It" was a ploy to have a little peace and quiet away from the "Hider".

Comment: Haha, *now* when I read this a year later, I have time to think about your joke about the seeker and the hider. *g*